# How to set focus to the tag-it widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tag-it

I simply want the tag-it widget to have focus after the page loads. I've tried various things like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#myTags").tagit("tagInput").click();
</script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#myTags").tagit("tagInput").focus();
</script>
```

and even more exotic things like use jQuery to modify the ID and call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#newIDiTriedToMake").focus();
</script>
```

Nothing I do seems to ever give keyboard focus to the tag-it widget. I must either tab through my page to it, or click it manually with the mouse to start entering tags. Anyone have clues for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're both on-track, that the document hasn't finished building (and therefore the element probably doesn't exist) when I'm trying to set the focus. However, I solved the problem the easy way: editing the source code.

I just added

```
this.tagInput.attr('autofocus', 'autofocus');
```

to the _create() method of tag-it, which gives the focus to the element without having to resort to Javascripty goodness. This worked.

Comment: I tried the other proposed solutions - embarassed to say I failed to put in the original question really that these were things I'd already tried. After some effort, mine was the only solution I could make work, so I'm calling my own answer the answer.

Comment: Although I did up-vote your answer, be aware that 'autofocus' is new in HTML5.

Comment: As much as I hate marking my own answer as the right one, in the end, it was the only thing I could make work, noting Ron's caveat: this is HTML5. Sad 'mote here.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you are missing is for the DOM to be built before you set focus.  That is if .tagit("tagInput") references a focusable element. You can try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
        $("#myTags").tagit("tagInput").focus();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you simply elaborate a little more about how this ensures the DOM is finished before doing its work? Benjamin's answer may or may not be correct (I haven't tried either yet), but his seems more self-documenting.

Comment: $(function() is equivalent to $(document).ready - it is just a short-hand. I do like your "autofocus" solution as well.

Comment: I've tried to use this advice to make it work, and it seems it's what I was already doing. You instantiate the tag-it widget in the $(document).ready area, so it seems my solution is the only one that works.

Answer (score 0):

You should focus when you have a document.ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#newIDiTriedToMake").tagit("tagInput").focus();
   })
</script>
```

Comment: I'll admit, I'm going to try going down Ron's route, since it seems modifying an element's ID is considered bad practice, and intuitively it seems a really bad idea.

Comment: Aha, I'm pretty sure this won't work, since it's exactly what I was doing. I should have given code context, but the place where I was modifying ID and setting focus was in the $(document).ready(f(){...})